# Is there an easy to install solution for self hosted wordpress (multiple sites possible)

Tags: wordpress, caching, nginx, redis, memcached

Do you know an easy to install and setup server side solution, to host many wordpress sites on one node like digital ocean or linode? I would like to have a ready-to-run solution utilizing nginx and caching technologie?

Any suggestion are very welcome!
Thank you in advance,

Ingo Baab

Comment: I would like a solution that uses lxd/lxc to isolate server systems, as discribed here:
https://bobcares.com/blog/wordpress-hosting-using-lxd-lxc-server-virtualization-solution/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you invest some R&D into WordPress Multisite, WPMU may deliver the exact results you desire. Perhaps, if that is not the solution you want, you'll want to snag some cPanel web hosting, so you can use Softaculous to fire-up as many WP instances as you wish using a GUI.

Did you explore the Digital Ocean community guides? I'm certain that is a good place to explore as well.